# Defining reusable media queries in SASS

Tags: media-queries, sass

I'm trying to do something like:

```
$media_not_desktop: '@media only screen and (max-width: 959px)';
```

then

```
.wrap {
  color: #fff;
  $media_not_desktop {
      color: #555;
  }
}
```

but I'm getting a syntax error. How would you do this?

Comment: Sass 3.2 is now available and stable. I did something similar because I wanted to reuse my media queries and create Responsive Web easily. Check my mixins: http://paranoida.github.com/sass-mediaqueries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is currently not a possible with Sass. There's an open issue with a patch on the [Sass bug tracker](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/106), though.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in sass 3.2, currently available as an alpha release
http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32 under **Variables as full query**.

The syntax is a little different but essentially the same functionality.